# How do I maintain zabbix for MongoDB backup? with ansible

Tags: mongodb, ansible, zabbix, maintenance-plan

I have to implement zabbix maintenance for Mongodb backup with ansible

the tasks are as follows:

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/5.4/en/manual/maintenance

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/zabbix/zabbix_maintenance_module.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ansible module is here: https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.zabbix

example:

```yaml
- name: Create a named maintenance window for host www1 for 90 minutes
  community.zabbix.zabbix_maintenance:
    name: Update of www1
    host_name: www1.example.com
    state: present
    minutes: 90
    server_url: https://...
    login_user: ...
    login_password: ...
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help.
let's assume that the module you exemplified in the comment above have to be as variables, how would it be? (dying hard :))

-I had to create a task folder (to put the main.yml)
and I think I have to create a defaults folder in which the variables should be, or am I wrong?

-about putting the module as variables is that I'm having a lot of difficulties!

-I believe that the variables also have to have the name zabbix_maintenance_<var>.....


for example:
zabbix_maintenance_login_user
zabbix_maintenance_login_url